# changing font colour in ListView, database, android

Tags: android, listview, colors

I was using this  [android list view tutorial](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)  (it shows how to display database entries in a list view), and I was thinking about changing color of the entries from database, is it possible to change color of every row ? For example Germany will be red, Spain yellow etc. and the color will depend on the string?

```
  // map each name to a TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "countryname" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };


 conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Countrylist.this, R.layout.country_view, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve through custom adapter,

In the custom adapter getView method, you can set the background for the textView based on your condition

Please find the references,

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=454

Comment: Thank You! this tutorial looks great :)